# Monoprice maker select v2 doesn't extrude but is not clogged

Tags: monoprice-maker-select

So I have been printing lately, and got a new spool of filament. It will extrude when I pre-heat the nozzle and manually extrude it, however when I start to print, it doesn't extrude any filament. Sometimes it works with different filament, but not always. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SE 3D Printing! Are you saying when you engage the extruder motor manually it pushes filament out, yet, when you try to do it through the print, you don't get anything? Or when you are saying "manually extrude it" you are physically pushing the filament out through the nozzle?

Comment: I am using the motor to extrude it manually

Comment: This is probably not enough information to help you. You need to add how you slice a file, add maybe a link to it or the first 20 lines. Does the extruder motor rotte at all?

Comment: The temperature is correct, and i slice it using Cura. The motor does rotate, but doesn't extrude.

Comment: When you add information, you need to update the question using [edit], not the comments. Comments are for others to request for information or remark. This is not a forum, SE sites work differently. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Any T-command in your gcode?

Answer (score 0):

- Try advancing the extruder manually using the control interface. Extrude about 10 cm of filament to verify that everything is OK with the machine.
- Is the filament curling on the way out of the nozzle? If so then there may really be a clog and you should clean it. Invest in some cleaning filament as well.
- The idler bearing may not be pushing down on the filament tightly enough. Check that the spring which holds it in place has not become soft or broken.
- The drive gear could be dirty. Plastic particle build up on the gear will cause it to slip. Clean the drive gear to remove all plastic build up.

Outside of this you could have a mechanical problem with extruder. Advance the motor using the control system (without filament installed) to verify that it is working properly.